# parent picklist automatically get selected if child selected

Tags: apex, picklist

How can I select parent values automatically to another picklist if any of its child is selected in a picklist? For example..

- parent picklist object11
- child  picklist object11
- child  picklist object13
- child  picklist object14
- parent picklist object22
- child  picklist object22

SO if i select **child picklist object14** then parent picklist object11 should be selected. Hope I was able express correctly .

Comment: Standard pages or custom pages ? Does it need to be instantly or can it be done by workflow ? Have you already tried something ?  MnZ, you're not new here, you ought to know by now that it helps you to get answers if you give some more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use dependent picklists for this: 
http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_defining_field_dependencies.htm&language=en_US

Besides limiting the amount of available children after selecting a parent  value, they also work the other way around. So whenever you try to change the child value on the page, it will automatically force you to also change the parent value.